# Convert 4 column melted data frame to 2 column data frame with matrix elements

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix, dataframe, data-conversion

Would appreciate advice in *converting a 4 column melted data frame to a 1 column data frame with elements as matrices*. I'm unsure of how to best do this but have tried acast, split + lapply to no avail. In the following, I provide a) expected input, b) expected output, and c) code for generating sample data.

**a) Expected input:** 4 column data frame with columns as... `identifier`: ID for each sample, `pixel`: pixel id within a sample, `color`: r, g, and b categories,`value`: r or g or b value

`input_frame`:

```
   identifier pixel color value
1           1     1 rgb_r   124
2           1     1 rgb_g   167
3           1     1 rgb_b   209
4           1     2 rgb_r   171
5           1     2 rgb_g    94
6           1     2 rgb_b   251
```

**b) Expected output:** data frame with 2 columns, one for `identifier`, the other for `rgb_matrix`, a matrix where rows = `pixel`, columns = `color`, and entries = `value`

`output_frame`:

```
   identifier    rgb_matrix
1           1    (rgb_matrix_1)
2           2    (rgb_matrix_2)
3           3    (rgb_matrix_3)
4           4     .
5           5     .
6           6     .
```

where `rgb_matrix_i` is pixel x color with entries as value:

```
   rgb_r rgb_g rgb_b
1    220   145    79
2    100   252   123
3     76    98   132
4    249     0    43
5    110   144    47
```

**c) Sample code:** code for generating sample input

```
# sample generation params
num_identifier = 10
num_pixel = 10
num_colordim = 3

# create sample data frame in melted form
identifier <- vector()
pixel <- vector()
for(i in 1:num_identifier){
  identifier <- c(identifier,rep(i,num_pixel*num_colordim))
  for(j in 1:num_pixel){
    pixel <- c(pixel,rep(j,num_colordim))
  }
}
color <- rep(c('rgb_r','rgb_g','rgb_b'), num_identifier*num_pixel)
value <- sample(0:255, num_identifier*num_pixel*num_colordim, replace = T)

input_frame <- data.frame(identifier, pixel, color, value)
```

Comment: Data.frames don't really like to hold matrices. Why do you need this? Would a standard list of matrices do?

Comment: Perhaps, its worth to take a look at `xtabs(value ~ pixel + color + identifier, input_frame)`, too; you could select your "indentifiers" by selecting the appropriate 3rd dimension.,

Comment: @MrFlick My goal is to make a distance matrix with distance as a function of the samples' distance matrices and other, externally provided values. I was thinking that I could first coerce the values into matrix format, store it in a df, join with the df containing externally provided values, then calculate. I will def. take a look into lists and xtab

Comment: @Jac if you plan to use the built-in `dist()` to calculate distance, you'll want a matrix where each row represents a sample so you'll probably be better off having each pixel/rgb value be it's own column for a given sample.

Comment: @MrFlick I was able to accomplish what I set out to do with a list :). I was trying to avoid allotting a column per pixel/rgb value.

Comment: Completed via:
split_frame <- split(input_frame,input_set$identifier)
output_list <- lapply(split_frame,function(x) acast(x,pixel ~ color_dim))